# Trying to convert RLE to ASCII but will not allow me to convert more than one line

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function which allows me to convert **RLE** inputted by the user in the form `'01h01e02l01o'` to convert into **ASCII** `'hello'`. The user needs to input each line separately and while my code lets me do the first line, an error message appears for any more.

```
def enterRLE():
    print ('\n' + 'You have selected option 1: Enter RLE')
    lineNo = 0
    lineNoList = []
    RLEList = []
    while lineNo <= 2:
        lineNo = int(input('How many lines of RLE would you like to input? Please enter a number over 2.   '))
    for i in range(lineNo):
        RLEData = input('\n' + "Please enter one line of RLE and press enter. Enter your code with two digits, for example '07c' or '40a'.   ")
        RLEList.append(RLEData)
        RLELength = len(RLEList)
        for i in range(RLELength):
            n = 3
            RLEData = [RLEData[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(RLEData), n)]
            for i in (RLEData):
                numOfChar = int(i[0:2])
                numOfChar = ((i[2:3])*numOfChar)
                print(numOfChar, end = "")
```

If I input the second line as '01h01a02l01w01a01y' the output should be 'hallway' and then it should ask me for my third line, however, the output is 'hallway' and thenthe following display error is shown:

```
File "rleConverter.py", line 16, in enterRLE
    numOfChar = int(i[0:2])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Comment: You are trying to use the variable name `i` for three different things at the same time.  Chose different names for each of your `for` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not really about RLE, but about basic programming knowledge/experience. So I'll give you some advices, based on the code in your question.

**What to do when code is not working as expected**

When your code is not working as expected, try to debug it first. There are several ways to do this:

- Step through your code using a debugger.
- Add some (temporary) print statements. For example, print a short debug message and the value of `i` in each loop to understand what's happening.

Using any of these methods you likely would have found the error(s) in your code.

**How to improve your code (so you'll avoid having to debug it)**

The biggest issue of your code has to do with naming stuff (mostly variables). Think about what variables you want to store, and name them appropriately. When reading code, it should be easy to "guess" from the variable name what the variable actually means.

- Don't use the same variable name multiple times with different meanings (in your code the variable `i` is used multiple times, which causes a problem).
- Don't create/define variables that you don't use. They only cause confusion. (For example, the variable `lineNoList` in your code is assigned but never used.)
- Follow the [Python naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions) to make your code more Pythonic and make it easier to read for other Python programmers.
- Use the [pep8 tool](https://pypi.org/project/pep8/) to check if your code complies to the standard naming conventions.
- Learn the basic Python language features. For example, in many cases the `for i in range(...)` construct is not necessary, but can be replaced by easier, more Pythonic code (e.g. `for line in lines: ...`, where `lines` is a list, tuple or other iterator, or `for line in file: ...`, where `file` is an open file). This is easier to read and reduces the number of variables you have to define.
- By writing shorter functions you'll also reduce the number of variables in a scope (i.e. inside the function), which reduces the code complexity, and consequently the chance of errors.

Furthermore, use [pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) to check your code while you're programming. It'll give you valuable feedback. In this case it reports the following message for line 12 and 15 of your code:

> Redefining name 'i' from outer scope (line 8)

So using pylint you would have found this bug already before running your code :-)

As an example, the following is a modified version of your code, which works correctly:

```py
def decode_rle(line):
    parts = [line[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(line), 3)]
    for part in parts:
        length = int(part[0:2])
        character = part[2]
        print(length * character, end='')


def enter_rle():
    print('\nYou have selected option 1: Enter RLE')
    num_lines = 0
    while num_lines <= 2:
        num_lines = int(input('How many lines of RLE would you like to input? Please enter a number over 2.   '))
    for _ in range(num_lines):
        line = input("\nPlease enter one line of RLE and press enter. Enter your code with two digits, for example '07c' or '40a'.   ")
        decode_rle(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    enter_rle()
```